# Custom image to occupy maximum width in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock and I am using a custom layout that displays an image instead of the Title, along with the icon on the left. So my code is

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_actionbar, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.LEFT);
    actionBar.setCustomView(view, params);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

So far the image is shown instead of title, but because of the menu items on the right, which are set to be shown "ifRoom", the image is scaled down to fit the remaining space on the ActionBar.

[image: Sample image]

My requirement is to get my image laid first and take the required space on ActionBar and then the menu items should appear if there is any room for them. I don't want to put all my menu items in overflow menu, as on bigger screens I want them to show up.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

I have been researching online about how to stop my action bar title from truncating (i.e. "My Longish Title" becoming "My Longish Ti...").  It looks like even if you use 'ifRoom' the title textview (or imageview in your case) has only a certain width it is allowed to use.

Possible ways round it include:

- Create a narrower image
- amend ifRoom to be never